# Add value to list of valid States

Tags: execute-anonymous, country-and-state

I added a new State for the Country 'Canada' in Setup -> State and Country/Territory Picklists. The State is 'BC' and StateCode is 'BC2'. See the image below for how it looks:

[image]

Now that 'BC' is a valid State, I should be able to update an address field with the State = 'BC' but I am getting the following error:

> First exception on row 0 with id 00Q1b000004oxi1EAA; first error:
>   FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, There's a problem with this state, even
>   though it may appear correct. Please select a state from the list of
>   valid states.: State/Province: [State]

Comment: Did you set the appropriate country as well? If you fail to do so, you'd get this error.

Comment: @sfdcfox I added the State by clicking 'Edit' beside Canada, then Add State. How do I set the appropriate country? Unless you mean that before setting the Lead's State to 'BC', I set the Country to 'Canada', which I did

Comment: @sfdcfox I did get it so that 'BC' is available under the 'State' picklist when I go to a Lead record which I didn't have working before. But i am still getting that error when updating the State through Apex. Any idea what might cause that? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. State integration values must match with State code.
   [image]
2. You need to set country as well while creating record as shown below

   ```
   Account objAccount = new Account(Name='Sample',
                      BillingCountry='Canada',
                      BillingState='BC2');
   ```

   INSERT objAccount;